# How do I get the value and type of a Literal in a procedural macro?

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I am implementing a function-like procedural macro which takes a single string literal as an argument, but I don't know how to get the value of the string literal.

If I print the variable, it shows a bunch of fields, which includes both the type and the value. They are clearly there, somewhere. How do I get them?

```
extern crate proc_macro;
use proc_macro::{TokenStream,TokenTree};

#[proc_macro]
pub fn my_macro(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let input: Vec<TokenTree> = input.into_iter().collect();
    let literal = match &input.get(0) {
        Some(TokenTree::Literal(literal)) => literal,
        _ => panic!()
    };

    // can't do anything with "literal"
    // println!("{:?}", literal.lit.symbol); says "unknown field"

    format!("{:?}", format!("{:?}", literal)).parse().unwrap()
}
```

```
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene)]
extern crate macros;

fn main() {
    let value = macros::my_macro!("hahaha");
    println!("it is {}", value);
    // prints "it is Literal { lit: Lit { kind: Str, symbol: "hahaha", suffix: None }, span: Span { lo: BytePos(100), hi: BytePos(108), ctxt: #0 } }"
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After running into the same problem *countless* times already, I finally wrote a library to help with this: [**`litrs`** on crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/litrs). It compiles faster than `syn` and lets you inspect your literals.

```
use std::convert::TryFrom;
use litrs::StringLit;
use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;


#[proc_macro]
pub fn my_macro(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let input = input.into_iter().collect::<Vec<_>>();
    if input.len() != 1 {
        let msg = format!("expected exactly one input token, got {}", input.len());
        return quote! { compile_error!(#msg) }.into();
    }

    let string_lit = match StringLit::try_from(&input[0]) {
        // Error if the token is not a string literal
        Err(e) => return e.to_compile_error(),
        Ok(lit) => lit,
    };

    // `StringLit::value` returns the actual string value represented by the
    // literal. Quotes are removed and escape sequences replaced with the
    // corresponding value.
    let v = string_lit.value();

    // TODO: implement your logic here
}
```

See [the documentation of `litrs`](https://docs.rs/litrs) for more information.

---

To obtain more information about a literal, `litrs` uses the `Display` impl of `Literal` to obtain a string representation (as it would be written in source code) and then parses that string. For example, if the string starts with `0x` one knows it has to be an integer literal, if it starts with `r#"` one knows it is a raw string literal. The crate `syn` does exactly the same.

Of course, it seems a bit wasteful to write and run a second parser given that rustc *already* parsed the literal. Yes, that's unfortunate and having a better API in `proc_literal` would be preferable. But right now, I think `litrs` (or `syn` if you are using `syn` anyway) are the best solutions.

---

(PS: I'm usually not a fan of promoting one's own libraries on Stack Overflow, but I am *very* familiar with the problem OP is having and I very much think `litrs` is the best tool for the job right now.)

Comment: can you expand on what your library does internally to solve this?

Comment: @SashaKondrashov I edited my answer and added some explanation. Does this explain it sufficiently?

Comment: I was also interested in how it internally works, and your explanation is plenty sufficient to my eyes

Answer (score 13):

If you're writing procedural macros, I'd recommend that you look into using the crates [`syn`](https://docs.rs/syn/*/syn/) (for parsing) and [`quote`](https://docs.rs/quote/*/quote/) (for code generation) instead of using `proc-macro` directly, since those are generally easier to deal with.

In this case, you can use [`syn::parse_macro_input`](https://docs.rs/syn/*/syn/macro.parse_macro_input.html) to parse a token stream into any syntatic element of Rust (such as literals, expressions, functions), and will also take care of error messages in case parsing fails.

You can use [`LitStr`](https://docs.rs/syn/*/syn/struct.LitStr.html) to represent a string literal, if that's exactly what you need. The `.value()` function will give you a `String` with the contents of that literal.

You can use [`quote::quote`](https://docs.rs/quote/*/quote/macro.quote.html) to generate the output of the macro, and use `#` to insert the contents of a variable into the generated code.

```rust
use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use syn::{parse_macro_input, LitStr};
use quote::quote;

#[proc_macro]
pub fn my_macro(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    // macro input must be `LitStr`, which is a string literal.
    // if not, a relevant error message will be generated.
    let input = parse_macro_input!(input as LitStr);

    // get value of the string literal.
    let str_value = input.value();

    // do something with value...
    let str_value = str_value.to_uppercase();

    // generate code, include `str_value` variable (automatically encodes
    // `String` as a string literal in the generated code)
    (quote!{
        #str_value
    }).into()
}
```

Comment: I looked into syn, and found it confusing to use. Also it seems overkill for what I was trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same with `syn` and float literal, and it does not have a `.value()` and seem impossible to convert into an actual float

Comment: @sukmel There's [`LitFloat::base10_digits`](https://docs.rs/syn/2.0.17/syn/struct.LitFloat.html#method.base10_digits) to get the number part of the literal (without the suffix, e.g. for `1.23e4f64` it'd give `"1.23e4"`), and there's [`LitFloat::base10_parse`](https://docs.rs/syn/2.0.17/syn/struct.LitFloat.html#method.base10_parse) which you can use to parse it into e.g. a `f32` or `f64` value.

Comment: @Frxsterm I found the former and used it with `f64::parse`, thanks for the hint about the latter, that's likely the same but it will look better

Answer (score -1):

I always want a string literal, so I found this solution that is good enough. `Literal` implements `ToString`, which I can then use with `.parse()`.

```
#[proc_macro]
pub fn my_macro(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let input: Vec<TokenTree> = input.into_iter().collect();
    let value = match &input.get(0) {
        Some(TokenTree::Literal(literal)) => literal.to_string(),
        _ => panic!()
    };
    let str_value: String = value.parse().unwrap();

    // do whatever

    format!("{:?}", str_value).parse().unwrap()
}
```

Comment: `value` is already a `String`, so `value.parse()` is a noop. Unfortunately, I don't think helps :/

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem for parsing `doc` attribute. It is also represented as a `TokenStream`. This is not exact answer but maybe will guide in a proper direction:

```
fn from(value: &Vec<Attribute>) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut lines = Vec::new();
    for attr in value {
        if !attr.path.is_ident("doc") {
            continue;
        }
        if let Ok(Meta::NameValue(nv)) = attr.parse_meta() {
            if let Lit::Str(lit) = nv.lit {
                lines.push(lit.value());
            }
        }
    }
    lines
}
```