# How to use variable in syn parse_quote

Tags: rust

I'm having issues finding how to use variables in `parse_quote` in the documentation.

I have a string variable that I need to insert into a turbofish statement I create with `parse_quote`.

Below are my attempts after reading some documentation and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169932/how-do-i-get-the-value-and-type-of-a-literal-in-a-procedural-macro).

```rust
let my_var = String::from("hello");

let stmt = syn::parse_quote! { handle.add_class<#(my_var)::#(my_var)>(); };
```

This fails to compile with a warning about expecting other keywords.

I've also tried the following based on the documentation for `parse_quote`.

```rust
let my_var = quote!("hello");

let stmt = syn::parse_quote! { handle.add_class<#(my_var)::#(my_var)>(); };
```

This throws a similar error to the one above.

Comment: What does `println!("{}", quote! { handle.add_class<#(my_var)::#(my_var)>();  });` ouput? Compare with the output when `my_var` is defined as: `let my_var = Ident::new("hello", Span::call_site());`

Comment: Please reduce your code to something which can reproduce specific errors, and then please include those errors in your question. The code you have provided has a lot of problems and doesn't look like it's the same code that you have been running (e.g. `String.from` instead of `String::from`...

Comment: It should be without parentheses and proper turbofish (`handle.add_class::<#my_var::#my_var>();`).